# Update the retrieve data from SQL Query that is in another table

Tags: sql

Hello Guys I am trying to retrieve data using this command:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [TS]
      ,[Id]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Email]
 FROM [tblData].[dbo].[Info]
```

This gives me a results:

```
TS: QWRTY  
ID: 191  
Name: Henrol  
Email: Email
```

I also have another tbl "tblNickName" where there is ID,Nickname column:

```
ID: 191  
NickName: Henjoe
```

Now I want to change my retrieved data to be something like this:

```
TS: QWRTY  
ID: Henjoe  -- The ID now is changed to their nick name from another table.  
Name: Henrol  
Email: @email
```

I don't really search what would be the syntax/or right query to do it.
Hope you help me. THanks !

Comment: It's called a join; in this case, an inner join.  That's what you should research. It's purely a SQL thing and nothing do with VB.NET.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks Dude !

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `INNER JOIN` for retrieve data from another table.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 I.[TS]
      ,N.NickName AS [Id]
      ,I.[Name]
      ,I.[Email]
 FROM [tblData].[dbo].[Info] I
    INNER JOIN [tblData].[dbo].[tblNickName] N ON I.[Id] = N.[Id]
```